# why the datasource shows as null of the Datagridview, when it's already has been assigned with data?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ado.net

I have the following code to fill datagridview from a returning datatable.

```
DataTable dtCourse = Course.GetAllCourses();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dgvAvailableCourses.Rows.Add();
    dgvAvailableCourses[0, i].Value = dtCourse.Rows[i][0];

    //set image
    dgvAvailableCourses[1, i].Value = SMSV100.Properties.Resources.media_playback_stop_6;

    dgvAvailableCourses[2, i].Value = dtCourse.Rows[i][1];
    dgvAvailableCourses[3, i].Value = dtCourse.Rows[i][2];
    dgvAvailableCourses[4, i].Value = dtCourse.Rows[i][3];
    dgvAvailableCourses[5, i].Value = dtCourse.Rows[i][4];
    dgvAvailableCourses[6, i].Value = dtCourse.Rows[i][5];
    dgvAvailableCourses[7, i].Value = dtCourse.Rows[i][6];

    Console.WriteLine(dgvAvailableCourses.DataSource);
}
```

`dgvAvailableCourses` is the `DataGridview` 
`dtCourses` is the returned `datatable` from the `GetAllCourses()`

As you can see I have mapped the columns of the `datagridview` to the columns of the `datatable` and added rows. Funny things is when I tried to read the `datasource` using the `console.writeline()` I've used a break point, it showed null for the `datasource`.

How come this is possible why this datasource showed as null while it already assigned with data through the loops?

How do I overcome this, I need to access the underlying table of this `datagridview` in order to do some calculations but I cannot do that because it shows as null?

PS- `Datagridview` shows data without any problems but it shows `null` for the `datasource`
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you didn't bind the DataGridView to your source, you're just adding rows manually. If you do `dgvAvailableCourses.DataSource = dtCourse`, I think that you will have the binding done "correcty" (I'm assuming that you had a good reason to use a loop instead of just settng the DataSource property).

Comment: yes 'cus I don't want all the columns to assign to datagriview : ) so in this case I need do create a binding source?

Comment: I think that you can, in design time, create the columns and then use the property `AutoGenerateColumns = false`. For the ASP.NET GridView it works like that. Otherwise, you can hide/remove the columns after binding them.